Proof of Newton's Formulas.
This is question 22 in section 14.6 in Dummit and Foote, I am trying to understand its solution:
(Newton's Formulas)Let $f(x)$ be a monic polynomial of degree $n$ with roots $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$ in some field $\Omega.$ Let $s_i \in \Omega$ be the elementary symmetric polynomial of degree $i$ evaluated at the roots, and define $s_i = 0$ for $i > n.$ For each $ i \geq 0,$ define $p_i = \alpha_1^i + \dots + \alpha_n^i.$ Prove Newton's formulas:
\begin{align*} 
  p_1 - s_1 &= 0 ,\\ 
p_2 - s_1p_1 + 2s_2 &= 0,\\
 p_3 - s_1p_2 + s_2p_1 - 3s_3 &= 0,\\
 \vdots\\
  p_i - s_1 p_{i - 1} + s_2 - p_{i - 2} - \dots + (-1)^{i-1} s_{i-1} p_1 + (-1)^i is_i &= 0. \end{align*}
Here Proof of Newton Girard formula symmetric polynomials I think a question that solved it (but for $k>2$ and I do not know why). I also did not get the idea of the solution given there and I think the suggestion for another way of solving it was pointed out in the comments.
Could anyone describe an easy way of proving this formulas please?

Made a tweak to the MathJax. Please check that this matches your intended content.

@BrianTung yes it matches, thanks :)

Wikipedia states
the identity as
$$k e_k(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \sum_{q=1}^k (-1)^{q-1}
e_{k-q}(x_1,\ldots,x_n) p_q(x_1,\ldots,x_n).$$
We have for the RHS
$$- \sum_{q=1}^k (-1)^q
[w^{k-q}] \prod_{r=1}^n (1+wx_r)
\sum_{s=1}^n x_s^q
\\ = - [w^k] \prod_{r=1}^n (1+wx_r)
\sum_{q=1}^k (-1)^q w^q
\sum_{s=1}^n x_s^q.$$
Here we may extend $q$ beyond $k$ to infinity owing to the coefficient
extractor in front and get
$$- [w^k] \prod_{r=1}^n (1+wx_r)
\sum_{q\ge 1} (-1)^q w^q
\sum_{s=1}^n x_s^q
\\ = [w^k] \prod_{r=1}^n (1+wx_r)
\sum_{s=1}^n \frac{wx_s}{1+wx_s}
= [w^{k-1}]
\left(\prod_{r=1}^n (1+wx_r)\right)'.$$
Here the differentiation is with respect to $w.$ Continuing,
$$ k [w^k] \prod_{r=1}^n (1+wx_r)
= k e_k(x_1,\ldots,x_n).$$
This is the claim.

I want the identities as they are in Dummit & Foote, I put a bounty on the linked question as I want a very simple solution within the limits of of D&F until section 14.6 please

or you can just tell me how these identities can be reduced to those of D&F please.

I looked at Wikipedia and I realized how can I go down to the identities I have, but I have a question for you, is this the simplest way of solvi g it?

what is the definition of $w$?
